# CSS animations don't play properly

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have an introductory portion of a site where 4 letters (SVGS) pop onto the screen. Most of the time, it plays just fine. On occasion however, sometimes one or two or all the images won't animate in at all. I'm not sure what could be causing this (it's not the cache), and a page refresh usually fixes it. Am I missing something? Should I wait for the images to load AND for the entire DOM to be ready?

Here is the relevant CSS (Sass).

**Animation:**

```
@keyframes bobble {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(124px) scale(0.8, 1.6);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-64px) scale(1.6, 0.8);
  }
  55% {
    transform: translateY(16px) scale(0.9, 1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**Styling**

```
.hello-header-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: bobble $animation-duration cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.57, 0.67, 1.53);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  will-change: transform, opacity;

  // Plays animations when images have loaded (JS)
  .is-ready & {
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
}
```

Each letter also has an animation delay which starts at 0.4s and increases by `0.3s` for each letter (so `letter 1 = 0.4s delay`, `letter 2 = 0.7s delay`, `letter 3 = 1s delay`, etc).

**Javascript**

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.hello-header img');
let counter = 0;
let hasScrolled = false;

// Animate after hello section images have loaded
[].forEach.call( imgs, function( img ) {
  img.addEventListener( 'load', ()=> {
    counter++;
    if ( counter === imgs.length ) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.js-hello-header')[0].classList.add('is-ready');
    }
  }, false );
});
```

Comment: Yes, you need to wait for your external resources to load before you can reference them in your JavaScript. Note `document.ready` fires before `window.onload`, even if all your resources are cached. You should run your code on `window.onload` event.

Comment: I tried running the function inside the onload event but no dice. It seems especially prevalent in Safari desktop, I wonder if it's a browser bug.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't see how anyone could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `translate` and `scale` with `translate3d` and `scale3d` (with the appropriate parameters).

`translate` and `scale` in general are very CPU expensive while their 3d counterparts utilize hardware acceleration from the graphics card and therefore play animations much smoother.

Comment: I thought that the will-change property engages the GPU? I'm getting ~60 frames on the animation, it's pretty smooth. It's just that sometimes some letters don't pop up.

Comment: Aha. Then you definitely need to wait for them to load. Still, consider this: https://caniuse.com/#search=will-change